# Group By 2 columns and Count then Sort the count for each key pair

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

most probably this questions has already been answered but I dont really find the solution:

I have something like this:

Using this query:

```
SELECT
   deparment,
   device,
   count(*) as times 
FROM
   routines
GROUP BY
   device,
   deparment
ORDER BY
   times DESC;
```

```
The result would come like this:

3   "A" 7337
2   "A" 5875
1   "A" 3242
3   "B" 1937
2   "B" 1866
3   "C" 1609
1   "B" 1580
3   "D" 1493
```

But i want to sort by each device so the output should be like this:

```
3   "A" 7337
2   "A" 5875
1   "A" 3242
3   "B" 1937
2   "B" 1866
1   "B" 1580
3   "C" 1609
3   "D" 1493
```

So the count field should be sorted from More to less but it has to be Grouped by each device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want two sort keys:

```
ORDER BY device, times DESC;
```

If you want to sort the *devices* as well, so the biggest device is first, you can use window functions:

```
ORDER BY sum(times) over (partition by device) DESC, device, times DESC
```

Comment: Yes it does group the device column and with the count but the times column gets unsorted so the first department,device,times set is not the one that has the max of times
Something like this happens:

 `3 "K" 3 `,

 `3 "X" 57 `,

 `2 "X" 23 `,

 `3 "J" 1 `,

 `2 "T" 2171 `,

Comment: @vml11 . . . This sorts by the devise and then `times` descending, which appears to be what you are asking for.

Comment: You are completly right the order by with that does what I was aiming for nevertheless the data displayed shows the times unsorted it does not sort the whole result by times starting with the row that has the most "times". Can that be achieved?

Comment: Thats completly right! Thank you so much I didn't know about over and partition I will look at the doc about it to understand about it more.